# Does a firebase storage reference update if its parameter is a reactive value when using with react-firebase-hooks useDownloadURL function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage, react-firebase-hooks

For my project, I am using next.js along with react-firebase-hooks and firebase. On my home page, I have something like this:

```js
let [userAuth, authLoading, authError] = useAuthState(auth);
let uid = userAuth ? userAuth.uid : "_";

let [userData, userDataLoading, userDataError] = useDocument(doc(db, "users", uid));
let [imageURL, imageURLLoading, imageURLError] = useDownloadURL(ref(imageStorageRef, uid));

let content = "";
```

`content` is the actual output of my home page component, and it gets updated depending upon values of all these other variables. `userAuth` is initially `undefined` for a few seconds even for logged in users, thus value of `uid` is *loading.png*.

During this time, `userData` remains undefined as theres no such document as "_". When `userAuth` does become defined, `uid` also becomes defined and the `useDocument` hook also gets updated so as to work with the new values of `uid`, and so a few seconds after this, value of `userData` also gets updated.

I was expecting the same to happen with the `useDownloadURL` hook and the value of `imageURL` but that doesn't happen. Initially `uid` is "_" so nothing is retrieved and `imageURL` is undefined. When `uid` becomes defined, the `useDownloadURL` hook gets updated, and `imageURL` get the desired value for a few renders, but for some reason a few more renders are called automatically, and the value of `imageURL` becomes `undefined` again.

I checked this by placing a `console.log(imageURL)` at the top level of my home page component. Each time I reload the page, initially `undefined` is printed for a few times, then an error for something not being found on the storage is displayed. I assume it is for the "_" file. Then, a few more `undefined` get printed. Then my desired URL gets printed for a few times, one more error message for something not being found on the storage comes up, and then `undefined` is printed a couple of times, before the initial renders stop.

I am not sure why the `imageURL` value gets `undefined` after a while, I can catch the URL by setting a global variable and then my page works fine, but I cannot understand this behavior, and it took me a long while to figure it out before being able to implement the global variable fix.

Also, the `useDownloadURL` doesn't work after that, if in future the same image is updated or changed, the hook doesn't get triggered.

Please tell me what is happening.